# Rails SEO url with city name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, seo

Initially, the URL was so:

```
site.com/cars/22
```

Then I connected gem [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

And URL becomes so:

```
site.com/cars/red-nisan
```

But I want to get an URL like:

```
site.com/london/cars/red-nisan
```

How to do it?

Comment: Can you post some samples of what you have tried so far as an edit of the question?

Comment: Modify your routes. Without any further explanation as to the situation this is the answer to *How to do it?* the route would end up being something like `get '/:city/cars/:id'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have a model called `Car` and in that model you have a field called `city`, and 'name'

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
      extend FriendlyId
      friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged

```
  def slug_candidates
    [
      :name,
      [:city, :name],
    ]
  end
end
```